# using prepared statement with libpq

Tags: c++, types, prepared-statement, libpq

creating a prepared statements using libpq - PQprepare && PQexecPrepared functions
and sending different parameters to this query.
how can I define types in this const Oid* paramTypes (like varchar, text, float and etc.')

Comment: Since the question is tagged _C++_ , did you consider to use _libpqxx_ instead ? Of course it uses _libpq_ under the hood, but it might be more convenient to use. Simple suggestion.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.